# wrap long words or long characters ignoring html tags

Tags: php, text, word-wrap

I need wrap long words, each one in span tags, example:

```
$string = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa{}^?¿*!-<a href="#">link here</a>aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaa';
```

I need print this:

( cut each 8 characters ignoring html tags )

```
"<span>aaaaaaaa</span>
<span>aaaaaaaa</span>
<span>{}^?¿*!-</span>
<a href="#">link here</a>
<span>aaaaaaaa</span>
aa
<br />
aaaa"
```

something like what makes facebook `(<span class="word_break"></span>)`

facebook code:

`<span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span><wbr></wbr><span class="word_break"></span>`

any idea? :)

thanks so much

Comment: What is the pattern that you are trying to wrap? And what so you mean by "something like what makes facebook ()"?

Comment: I try with this: `preg_replace('~[^\s\n\r\t]+~', '<span></span>', $text)`

facebook wrap with span tags

`<span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span><wbr></wbr><span class="word_break"></span>`

Comment: Well if your using php you could try `chunk_split ( $string, 8 );` to spilt the string up and the just put that into a span in your loop

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you hit the roadblock? This would be useful to add because otherwise it seems you ask for a complete solution and that's a bit disliked on this site so you might not see that much attention with your question otherwise (I for example only comment here because I see it's your first question so you get some extra review from the community).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was a little off. You need str_split(); this should give you a workable array.

```
$str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa{}^?¿*!-<a href="#">link here</a>aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaa';

print_r(str_split($str, 8));

**This will return** 

(
    [0] => aaaaaaaa
    [1] => aaaaaaaa
    [2] => {}^*!-<a
    [3] =>  href="#
    [4] => ">link h
    [5] => ere</a>a
    [6] => aaaaaaaa
    [7] => a<br />a
    [8] => aaa
)
```

[Look at the docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Just loop through that adding a span to each loop.

**EDIT**

I just realized that this won't solve the problem of "ignoring the HTML tags". You could probably tweak it real quick. Just don't go down the [*DARK ROAD*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) of parsing HTML with REGEX please. Aloha.

Answer (score 0):

I wrong a PHP functio for it `word_wrap`

```
<?php
$string = 'abcdefghijklmnop{}^??*!-<a href="#">link here</a>abcdefghij<br />abcd';

print_r(word_wrap($string));

// Function Starts Here
function word_wrap($string, $chunk_size = 8) {
    $offset = 0;
    $result = array();
    while(preg_match('#<(\w+)[^>]*>.*?</\1>|<\w+[^>]*/>#', $string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
        if($match[0][1] > $offset) {
            $non_html = substr($string, $offset, $match[0][1] - $offset);
            $chunks = str_split($non_html, $chunk_size );
            foreach($chunks as $s) {
                // Wrap text with length 8 in <span>, otherwise leave as it is
                $result[] = (strlen($s) == $chunk_size  ? "<span>" . $s . "</span>" : $s);
            }
        } 
        // Leave HTML tags untouched
        $result[] = $match[0][0];
        $offset = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
    }
    // Process last unmatched string
    if(strlen($string) > $offset) {
        $non_html = substr($string, $offset);
        $chunks = str_split($non_html, $chunk_size );
        foreach($chunks as $s) {
            $result[] = strlen($s) == $chunk_size  ? "<span>" . $s . "</span>" : $s;
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

which produces the output of

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span>abcdefgh</span>
    [1] => <span>ijklmnop</span>
    [2] => <span>{}^??*!-</span>
    [3] => <a href="#">link here</a>
    [4] => <span>abcdefgh</span>
    [5] => ij
    [6] => <br />
    [7] => abcd
)
```