# Wrap each letter of a string in a tag, avoiding HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, word-wrap

I'd like to build a function that takes a string and wraps each of its letters in a `<span>`, except spaces and HTML tags (in my case, `<br>` tags).

So:

```
"Hi <br> there."
```

... should become

```
"<span>H</span><span>i</span> <br> <span>t</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>r</span><span>e</span><span>.</span>"
```

I had no luck coming up with my own solution so I looked around and I found it surprisingly hard to find exactly what I was looking for.

The closest I found was Neverever's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593155/wrap-long-words-or-long-characters-ignoring-html-tags).

However, it didn't seem to work that well, as each character of the `<br>` tags were wrapped in a `<span>` and it didn't match accentuated characters such as éèàï.

How should I proceed with this?
And why does parsing HTML tags with regex seem so wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you want to achieve, rather than asking for help with a solution which you think might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse HTML and wrap only chars within the value of [DOMText](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) nodes. See comments in code.

```
// Define source
$source = 'H&iuml; <br/> thérè.';

// Create DOM document and load HTML string, hinting that it is UTF-8 encoded.
// We need a root element for this so we wrap the source in a temporary <div>.
$hint = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($hint . "<div>" . $source . "</div>");

// Get contents of temporary root node
$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

// Loop through children
$next = $root->firstChild;
while ($node = $next) {
    $next = $node->nextSibling; // Save for next while iteration

    // We are only interested in text nodes (not <br/> etc)
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        // Wrap each character of the text node (e.g. "Hi ") in a <span> of
        // its own, e.g. "<span>H</span><span>i</span><span> </span>"
        foreach (preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $node->nodeValue) as $char) {
            $span = $dom->createElement('span', $char);
            $root->insertBefore($span, $node);
        }
        // Drop text node (e.g. "Hi ") leaving only <span> wrapped chars
        $root->removeChild($node);
    }
}

// Back to string via SimpleXMLElement (so that the output is more similar to
// the source than would be the case with $root->C14N() etc), removing temporary
// root <div> element and space-only spans as well.
$withSpans = simplexml_import_dom($root)->asXML();
$withSpans = preg_replace('#^<div>|</div>$#', '', $withSpans);
$withSpans = preg_replace('#<span> </span>#', ' ', $withSpans);

echo $withSpans, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
<span>H</span><span>ï</span> <br/> <span>t</span><span>h</span><span>é</span><span>r</span><span>è</span><span>.</span>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'd never used the DOMDocument class before, so not only did you answer my question, you also made me discover something I wasn't aware of. One thing though: accentuated characters [éèà...] don't seem to be picked up and the function prints `�` character whenever it encounters one. Any idea how I could solve that? Thanks again!

Comment: The DOMDocument can actually be quite handy. Have a look at DOMXPath as well while you're at it :) The loadHTML() function assumes ISO-8859-1 by default, so for UTF-8 characters to work you will need to convert the string using `$source = mb_convert_encoding($utf_8, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` or hint the encoding in the source. I have updated my answer with the latter solution.

Comment: ... and yes, the `str_split` was replaced by a `preg_split` with multibyte support as well. Grabbed from [an example](http://tz1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the result with a `([^\s>])(?!(?:[^<>]*)?>)` regex. To enable Unicode support, just use it with `u` option:

```
<?php
   $re = "/([^\\s>])(?!(?:[^<>]*)?>)/u"; 
   $str = "Hi <br> there."; 
   $subst = "<span>$1</span>"; 
   $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
   echo $result;
?>
```

Here you can find the [regex explanation and demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS0hR9/3).

See [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbE9IcV91N0ttYWc) without Unicode support and here is [one with Unicode support](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRFByVWxEM09CY2c) (the difference is in `u` option).

Comment: Thank you! As for mhall's answer, yours seems to work just fine until accented characters such as é or à come into play.

Comment: To enable Unicode support in PHP regex, you need to add `u` modifier to the end of the regex: `/([^\\s>])(?!(?:[^<>]*)?>)/u`. See updated sample program at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRFByVWxEM09CY2c.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like ...

```
<?php

  $str = "Hi <br> there.";
  $newstr = "";
  $notintag = true;
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    if (substr($str,$i,1) == "<") {
      $notintag = false;
    }
    if (($notintag) and (substr($str,$i,1) != " ")) {
      $newstr .= "<span>" . substr($str,$i,1) . "</span>";
    } else {
      $newstr .= substr($str,$i,1);
    }

    if (substr($str,$i,1) == ">") {
      $notintag = true;
    }


  }
  echo $newstr;

?>
```